# Excel to PDF multiple ranges

Tags: excel, pdf, presentation, vba

This is the current code that I have - and I keep getting a 1004 runtime error - range. Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
Sub ToPDF()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("KPIs").Select
    Range("B3:Y46,AA3:AX46,AZ3:BW46,BY3:CV46,CX3:DU46,DW3:ET46,EV3:FS46,B48:Y91,AA48:AX91,AZ48:BW91,BY48:CV91,CX48:DU91,DW48:ET91,EV48:FS91,B93:Y136,AA93:AX136,AZ93:BW136,BY93:CV136,CX93:DU136,DW93:ET136,EV93:FS136,B138:Y181,AA138:AX181,AZ93:BW181,BY138:CV181,CX138:DU181").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
             "C:\Users\strzelecki-e\Desktop\Macros\KPIs.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
             IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Sheets("KPIs").Select` to `Sheets("KPIs").Activate`. Especially with newer versions of Excel `.Select` has been reported to create errors.

`Range("B3:Y46,AA3:AX46,AZ3:BW46,BY3:CV46,CX3:DU46,DW3:ET46,EV3:FS46,B48:Y91,AA48:AX91,AZ48:BW91,BY48:CV91,CX48:DU91,DW48:ET91,EV48:FS91,B93:Y136,AA93:AX136,AZ93:BW136,BY93:CV136,CX93:DU136,DW93:ET136,EV93:FS136,B138:Y181,AA138:AX181,AZ93:BW181,BY138:CV181,CX138:DU181")`

That's too long. There seems to be a limit for 255 characters between the quotations and (at the moment) there are 260 characters. If you remove only the last part and thereby shorten it to 255 characters then it will work.

Alternatively you can also do the following:

```
Dim r As Range

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KPIs").Activate

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KPIs").Range("B3:Y46,AA3:AX46,AZ3:BW46,BY3:CV46,CX3:DU46,DW3:ET46,EV3:FS46,B48:Y91,AA48:AX91")
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KPIs").Range("AZ48:BW91,BY48:CV91,CX48:DU91,DW48:ET91,EV48:FS91,B93:Y136,AA93:AX136,AZ93:BW136,BY93:CV136,CX93:DU136,DW93:ET136,EV93:FS136"))
Set r = Union(r, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KPIs").Range("B138:Y181,AA138:AX181,AZ93:BW181,BY138:CV181,CX138:DU181"))
r.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\tmp\KPIs.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Basically, I have merely split the range into several shorter bits and `add` them together with `union` to the final range you asked for.

Comment: The code works, but im having problems with the charts being to small and then 2 of the charts are on the same page.

Comment: Can you help me with the sizing of the charts and the 2 charts on the same page thing by chance?
And I cant vote up cuz I guess im still still a newbie here :)

Comment: If you have a new question then please feel free to post a new question. I will be happy to have a look at it (just like all the others here). But it very much sounds to me that you want to change the formatting of the PDF result. Yet, doing so without defining page breaks, zooms, page layouts is almost impossible. So, you'll probably have to create a new Excel file (or sheet) for the purpose of printing only. In this Excel file (or sheet) you can properly format all you want and then print to PDF with the above command.

Comment: Ralph - Thank you so much for your help I managed to find the error on my side which fixed everything. Thank you again!